# JSONB change params value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table that contains a json type in one row called ***whole_params***, and I would like to change values if json param called ***exampleParam*** equals ***value1*** I want to change it to ***value2***

```
UPDATE table_name t 
SET whole_params = json_set(whole_params, '{exampleParam}')::jsonb)
WHERE t.whole_params ->> 'exampleParam' = 'value1';
```

I wrote something like that but I do not know how to change that 'value1', any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `jsonb_set()` instead of `json_set()` with a slight change as

```
UPDATE table_name t 
  SET whole_params = jsonb_set(whole_params, '{exampleParam}','"value2"') 
WHERE t.whole_params ->> 'exampleParam' = 'value1';
```